# Large delay when using animate feature on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a feature where the navbar-brand and nav-items toggle between two widths and font sizes respectively when you scroll from the top. However, there is a huge delay when I attempt to animate them, whereas using just the css method works just fine. What's going on here?

```
var $logoImage = $('.logo-image');
var $navItem = $('.nav-item');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        $logoImage.css("width", "200px");
        $navItem.css("font-size", "1.3rem");
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $logoImage.css("width", "125px");
            $navItem.css("font-size", "1rem");
        } else {
            $logoImage.css("width", "200px");
            $navItem.css("font-size", "1.3rem");
        }
    });
});
```

The $logoImage is the logo in the navbar-brand.

Comment: Instead of assigning to $logoImage and $navItem, have you tried dropping in $(".logo-image") and $(".nav-item")  ?

Comment: I just tried that and it's giving me the same error. In addition, the animate functions aren't firing correctly on page scroll for some reason. I included a console log to confirm that the condition would fire but the functions aren't.

Comment: Try reporting the jquery objects to the console, make sure they are valid. length should be > 0, console.dir($('.logo-image'));